# Question about nSudoku if we assume that it is NP-complete

Tags: module, computation, np-complete

Explain why each of the following statements is correct. You may assume that nSudoku is NP-complete.
If nSudoku can be reduced in polynomial time to factorization, then factorization is NP-complete.
If nSudoku can be reduced in polynomial time to the problem of sorting an integer array, then P = NP.
Any ideas how to explain? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

In order to determine if a problem (A) is NP-Complete, we must take four steps:

1. Prove that A is in NP
2. Transform a known NP Complete problem (B) into A in polynomial time
3. Prove that an answer to A is an answer to B
4. Prove that an answer to B is an answer to A

In your problem, you start with the known NP-Complete problem nSudoku, with the goal to first show that factorization is also NP-Complete. To do this, we would first show that factorization is in NP. You then provide the information that nSudoku can be transformed to factorization in polynomial time. If we then show that an answer to nSudoku is an answer to factorization and vice versa, then we have proven that factorization is NP-Complete.

We will then follow this same pattern for factorization and the problem of sorting an integer array to prove that the problem of sorting an integer array is NP Complete (starting with the fact that factorization is in NP). This, however, complicates things, because the problem of sorting an integer array is actually in P, as you can sort an integer array in O(nlogn), which is polynomial time.

At the core of this question is the "P versus NP problem", which is an unsolved problem that asks whether every problem in NP is really in P (in other words if every problem that has a decision problem that can be verified in polynomial time can ALSO be solved in polynomial time). To this date, there is no answer to the problem.

However, in your problem we prove that a problem that is known to be P is also NP complete, which then results in the conclusion stated in your problem that P=NP.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) to learn about the proper way to ask about homework questions.